# What are the conditions for overlapping 2D flatformer animation?

Tags: unity-game-engine

If my character jump with right-arrow Key, a running animation comes out instead of a character's jumping animation.
What should I do to make the jump animation come out?

This is my Player Code

```cs
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
    {
        if(collision.gameObject.name.Equals("platform_through"))
        {
            isJump = false;
            animator.SetBool("IsJump", false);

        }
    }

    private void PlayerMove()
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
            animator.SetBool("IsRun", true);
        }
        else if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 180f, 0f);
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(speed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0));
            animator.SetBool("IsRun", true);
        }
        else
        {
            animator.SetBool("IsRun", false);
        }

        // Jump
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            if (!isJump)
            {
                isJump = true;
                rigid.velocity = Vector3.zero;
                rigid.AddForce(Vector2.up * jumpPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
                animator.SetBool("IsJump", true);
            }
        }

    }
```

[image]
I tried to change my code order and Animator's Parameters order.

Comment: I think that the animator state machine is required to answer this question.

Comment: @Voidsay I put an animator picture on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your AnimatorController setup as soon as you are running (`isRun = true`) there is no available transition to the jump state.

You would need additional transitions forth and back between run and jump state as well and treat the flags accordingly like e.g.

```
idle -> jump: conditions - isJump
idle -> run: conditions - isRun
run -> jump: conditions - isJump
run -> idle: conditions - !isRun
jump -> idle: conditions - !isJump && !isRun
jump -> run: conditions - !isJump && isRun
```

and then further also

```
idle -> attack: condition - isAttack
run -> attack: conditions - isAttack
jump -> attack: conditions - isAttack
attack -> idle: conditions - !isAttack && !isJump && !isRun
attack -> jump: conditions - !isAttack && isJump
attack -> run: conditions - !isAttack && isRun
```

So the states/flags will overrule each other in the hierarchy

```
attack > jump > run > idle
```